# Better design to displaying a lot of data within tables

Tags: web-app, layout, tables

This is the current design

[image]

There could be hundreds of the 'panels' with tables that expand underneath when clicked. The tables could contain thousands of rows.

What would be a better way of displaying this?

The tables contain errors which users can do multiple things with, any suggestions?

Comment: Who is the user and what is their goal?

Answer (score 1):

If a panel is expanded and it has thousands of rows, then the below panel will be unreachable if you don't collapse the panel.

**My suggestion is using pagination for both the panels and the rows in the panel**. So you present a limited number of panels per page and a limited number of rows per panel.

You might also want to give the option to **view the full panel**. This should open either in a Dialog or in a different page.

Take a look at [Material design - Tables within cards](https://material.io/guidelines/components/data-tables.html#data-tables-tables-within-cards).

Answer (score 0):

One question you have to ask yourself is "**What is your user willing to do with those thousands lines of data**"?

I think that is better to **focus on a useful research interface** than just displaying data that user won't read.

Once the number of data to display is reduced by the filter, you would be able to think more easily to a nice User Interface.

Answer (score 0):

If these base cards are just titles then why have the data rows contained within a card at all?  This seems like the perfect case of running a simple data table that the user can filter with a free text search to target the types and content of the rows that will be the of the most interest to them.

Now if this base card idea was done for performance reasons then it kind of makes since as long as the card carries a count of how may rows will be displayed when opened.  This will help inform the user of the impact of their choice of opening a card.

In essence though what it seems to be is the same issue that most retailers have already tackled with a left hand filter set married with a free text search and then just displaying the results as either table line items or cards.  Either way your starting idea seems to create more surprises for the users rather than provide them with information to guide them to the work they need to do.